# Tips on refactoring unstructured repetitive code into reusable components

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have searched and searched and could not get any relevant answer. Hopefully someone can help.

I started writing classes as a sort of unit hold data and another util class to populate the class from the database. Well this might not seem to big of a problem for a small code base but looking forward and for me to grow to a competent developer with a solid grasp of object orientated design and development i need to grow this into a proper design

Lets start of with the initial class

```
public class Foo
{
   public int FooID {get;set;}
   public string FooName {get;set;}
   public string FooDescription {get;set;}
}

public class NotRelatedToFoo
{
   public int SomeID {get;set;}
   public string SomeName {get;set;}
   public string SomeDescription {get;set;}
}


public class Util
{
   public Util(){} 

   public List<NotRelatedToFoo> GetNotRelatedToFoos(string SomeName)
   {
     .... DB Code to return Data from DB 

     List<NotRelatedToFoo> notfoos = new List<NotRelatedToFoo>()
     (select * from NotRelatedToFoo where SomeName like @SomeName)
     foreach var item in db
     {
       NotRelatedToFoo notfoo = new NotRelatedToFoo ();
       notfoo.SomeID = item.SomeID;
       notfoo.SomeName = item.SomeName
       notfoo.SomeDescription = item.SomeDescription 
       notfoos.Add(notfoo);
      }
      return notfoos ;
   }

}
```

My question is what is the best way to move forward from this design.

**Edit** 
At the moment the Util class is a big mess and i need advice how to extract and group the functions together follow a structured design

This is not going to work, or can it

```
public class Foo
{
   public int FooID {get;set;}
   public string FooName {get;set;}
   public string FooDescription {get;set;}

   public List<Foo> GetFoos(string FooName)
   {
     .... DB Code to return Data from DB 

     List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>()
     (select * from foo where FooName like @FooName)
     foreach var item in db
     {
       Foo foo = new Foo();
       foo.FooID = item.FoodID;
       foo.FooName = item.FooName
       foo.FooDescription = item.FooDescription 
       foos.Add(foo);
      }
      return foos;
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This question should earn @AntiPatternMax a "Best Title" badge. :)

Comment: Please edit your question title to something sensible...

Comment: That's quite a title, but still hasn't too much to do with the question

Comment: Maybe you couldn't get a relevant answer because you didn't ask a relevant question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is what is the best way to move forward from this design.

Classes named `Util` or `Manager` or what have you are generally a design smell. You should be able to describe what it is that the class is doing (it should have a single responsibility) and that should be the name of the class. If you have to use generic, vague, catch-all terms to describe what the class is doing then you are doing something wrong and a redesign is in order.

Your `Util` class is doing too much. It's getting data from a database for two distinct types. By designing your class in this way, you are setting yourself up to violate the open/closed principle (you will have to modify this class every time you add a new type to your model).

At a minimum, you need separate classes to get `Foo`s and `NotRelatedToFoo`s from a database. How about

```
abstract class Repository<T> {
     IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}

abstract class SqlRepository<T> : Repository<T> {
    protected readonly SqlConnection connection;
    public SqlRepository(SqlConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
}

class FooRepository : SqlRepository<T> {

    public FooRepository(SqlConnection connection) : base(connection) { }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() {
    }
}
```

etc. What's really sick is that you can even lift a lot of the repetitive code of hydrating an object from an `IDataReader` into a common class (hint: a first version would use reflection).

Beyond this, read about [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29). And if you really want to dive it, try Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (Fowler) and Design Patterns (Gamma et al.)

Comment: +1. I hope all the library authors who made me use multiple totally unrelated `Manager` classes in the same program are reading along.

Comment: I like this, i would really appreciate it if you can expand on the code example you provided

Comment: Better yet, get an ORM like NHibernate so you can deal more with the objects in *your* app (and less with the common objects needed in your infrastructure).

Comment: @Berryl: While your comment is correct (everyone should use ORMs), switching to an ORM doesn't help with the fact that the OP is trying to get unconfused about OOP.

Answer (score 0):

the common way to access the database, is through data access objects. http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html

Don't know, if you have other classes for persisting, updating, or deleting data, but I usually do CRUD operations through a DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Util` class is responsible for many things (as Jason pointed out earlier).

It appears though that at the crux of it, `Util` is attempting to be a repository for your `Foo` and `UnrelatedToFoo` objects.

I would personally look at abstracting this out into some inheritance structures and introducing generics.

If you're going to be be creating a lot of these POCO objects that map to database tables in repetitive and convention based ways, consider an ORM such as NHibernate with FluentNHibernate mappings.

Comment: Thanks, I have used Linq to SQL and Subsonic but i NEED to know how this all works. I think a lot of developers know how to use the nice add-ons but don't have a clue on how to implement it themselves.

Comment: 'but don't have a clue on how to implement it themselves' - I agree. I have a vague idea how NHibernate works, but not in detail and wouldn't for a second think I could implement it myself.  But thats fine with me, I'm sticking to my knitting. Do you **really** need to know how it works to a level of detail that you could implement it yourself?  If you set out to truly understand everything you use you'll achieve mediocrity at best.  Don't re-invent the wheel, and have faith and trust 3rd party components used by hundreds of other developers world wide.